# SAGA dissolve tool keep only one column of data

Tags: saga, dissolve, qgis-2.12

I have installed QGIS 2.12 Lyon and I need to dissolve multiple polygons according to one column in the dbf file (my layer is a shapefile).

I have used SAGA "Polygon dissolve by attribute" algorithm and it works OK. The issue is that in my original file I have 7 columns, one of which is used to dissolve the polygons. The dbf file of the new layer has only 1 field - the one used to dissolve polygons.

How do I force SAGA to keep my other fields?

I just need one entry for each new polygon - information is repeated anyway.

Using the interface I could not see any option to select a method to retain information for other fields.

Comment: What if the other columns have different contents? Should the values be written as comma separated list or what?

Comment: Hi. For this specific set of data I did not mind, since I knew that all those fields had repeated values for the same dissolving records. Ideally there should be a list of different options depending on the field type. For example, for a string there should be: first, last, max, min, distinct list, full list, count. For numeric, I would expect min, max, sum, mean, median, count.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what I wanted but it's a workaround.
I have imported both layers in QGIS.
On my new layer I selected "Properties", then selected "Joins".
I have added a new Join and set up as:
Join layer: old layer
Join field: field used to dissolve polygons
Target field: the only field in the table
Choose which field are joined: checked the box and selected few fields from the original file.

Clicked OK and my new layer dbf file has additional fields.